# Trying to cast an int to a character in a que

Tags: java

I have a queue of integers and characters and I want to cast them all as chars.

```
Queue<Object> RPNque = new LinkedList<Object>();
RPNque.add(3);
RPNque.add('+');

char ch1= (char) RPNque.poll();
```

not working, trying to cast the object so i can do math operators on them

Comment: You could use `instanceof` to test whether the object is an `Integer` or a `Character`, but perhaps you should consider creating a `Token` class that can hold a number or an operator, and using polymorphism to determine what to do with them.

Comment: Your problem is that you can cast an int to a char, but you can't do the same between Integer and Character, and as Collection won't support primitive data types, when you do add, your values are being converted from int to Integer and from char to Character.

Answer (score 0):

Write your `Queue` so that it only contains `Character`.

```
Queue<Character> rpnQueue = new LinkedList<>();
```

Then, write a `switch` or equivalent `if-else` statement to determine if the character you've polled is an operator.

You will have to do the conversions yourself back and forth to `int` (simply put, if it isn't an operator, subtract `'0'` (the `char 0`)).

Comment: And what if the integers can be larger than 9? Negative?

Comment: Probably should be using `String` instead of `Character` then.